# SSIS - Remove quotes from variable

Tags: ssis

I have a ZS REST API Task in SSMS that does a POST call to a REST API endpoint which returns a value in the body. As part of the Rest API Task, I store the response in a variable called "AuthToken"... the problem is when I attempt to use the variable in subsequent steps, it errors out because of the quotation marks.

I've looked for some tasks in the SSIS Toolbox panel, but can't find anything that would satisfy this requirement. All the other SO questions refer to trimming quotation marks from columns, but I just want to trim a VARIABLE.
[image]

Comment: If it is just a variable with one value, you can create a second variable that uses expression to replace quotes, and then use the 2nd variable with quotes removed wherever you need to use it.